# What is happening when I add a reference in VS?

Tags: c#, asp.net, dll

What is actually happening when I add a reference (to project / dll) to current project ?
Is it just about copying referenced dll's to current project bin folder ? I'm pretty sure there is more than that to it. Any suggested read please ?

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/wkze6zky.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Change the .csproj file extension to .xml and take a look at what was actually added, its all just Microsoft proprietary xml.
I think you'll find the reference is now under an element called "itemgroup" mid way down the file.

Comment: if you just unload the project in VS and right click you can edit it and get intellisense for it